# Cakephp 3 - Create full url

Tags: url, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

What I like to do is creating a full url.

```
Controller = 'A'
Action = 'doSomething'
param1 = $id
param2 = $id2
```

What I currently get is: 
mydomain.com/A/doSomething?param1=X&param2=XX

What I want is: 
mydomain.com/A/doSomething/X/XX

Code:

```
$message = 'Test: '. Router::url([
    "controller" => "A",
    "action" => "doSomthing",
    "param1" => $id,
    "param2" => $id2,
    '_full' => true
]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$id1 = 'id1';
$id2 = 'id2';

$url= Router::url([
    "controller" => "A",
    "action" => "doSomething",
    $id1,
    $id2,
    '_full' => true
]);

debug($url);
```

Outputs:

> 'http://host/a/do-something/id1/id2'

Comment: Thanks, actually logical

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
public function doSomthing($param1, $param2)
{
#your code here
}
```

Comment: I already have that. The parameters are not recongized with my setup. If I manually do this: mydomain.com/A/doSomething/X/XX, everything is fine. The problem is the URL builder.